# How to set RadioLisTile widget take as minimum space as it needs

Tags: flutter, flutter-radiobutton

I have used flexible widget here but  that just dividing the space equaly for every widget.
But I want them to take as minimum as they need  because some title has more lenth.

I have seen that If I dont give them Flexible or Extended widget on RadioListTile then it take infinity width and they got disapeare.

Here is my Code.

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Text('Content 1'),
            Text('Content 2'),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Straw/ Bamboo/ polyhtene/ plastic/ canvas',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Straw/ Bamboo/ polyhtene/ plastic/ canvas',
                        style: style),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Soil/ Brick',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Soil/ Brick', style: style),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Tin ( CICit)',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Tin ( CICit)', style: style),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Wood',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Wood', style: style),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Brick-Cement',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Brick-Cement', style: style),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                    value: 'Others',
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                    onChanged: onChangedMethod,
                    title: Text('Others', style: style),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is my output

[image: This is My OutPut]

This is what I want to achive

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `RadioListTile` with `Radio` widget. Wrap horizontal dynamic text list widget with **SizedBox** & give fixed **height**.

**try this code:**

```
SizedBox(
  height: 80,
  child: Scrollbar(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: List.generate(
        radioListItem.length,
        (i) => Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Radio(
              value: radioListItem[i],
              groupValue: (value) {},
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            Text(
              radioListItem[i],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Your code works like a charm. I just did not want a scroll view so i just change your code a bit with wrap .

Answer (score 0):

RadioListTile wrap with container not Flexible and give width of container then use list view instead row and listview wrap with expanded widget

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Text('Content 1'),
        Text('Content 2'),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Straw/ Bamboo/ polyhtene/ plastic/ canvas',
                  onChanged: (val){},
                  groupValue: value,
                  title: Text('Straw/ Bamboo/ polyhtene/ plastic/ canvas',
                     ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Soil/ Brick',
                  groupValue: value,
                  onChanged: (val){},
                  title: Text('Soil/ Brick', ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Tin ( CICit)',
                  onChanged: (val){}, groupValue: value,
                  title: Text('Tin ( CICit)',),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Wood',
                  onChanged: (val){}, groupValue: value,
                  title: Text('Wood',),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Brick-Cement',
                  onChanged: (val){}, groupValue: value,
                  title: Text('Brick-Cement', ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0),
                  value: 'Others',
                    onChanged: (val){}, groupValue: value,
                  title: Text('Others',),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided force you to apply a max width which I understand is not what you want. Wrapping your `RadioListTile` widget with `IntrinsicWidth` will do that you want.

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: RadioListTile(
    ...
  ),
)
```